# Play sound from assets in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using unity 3d and i am trying to play a sound from assets.
I have created a folder music inside assets and i have one sound clip called music.mp3.

I created also a c# file and put the code bellow and i attached this c# file on camera. Unfortunately it's not play.

```
void Start()
    {
AudioSource audio = gameObject.AddComponent < AudioSource > ();
            audio.PlayOneShot ((AudioClip)Resources.Load ("music"));
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Where did you put the audio file? Which directory? You can save both of us time by simply uploading a screenshot of where the image you want to play is located

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the `Resources.Load` documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html):

> The path is relative to any Resources folder inside the Assets folder of your project

I'm not sure if you have created a "Resources"-Folder inside the "Assets"-Folder (or any place you want it to be), if not create one and move your "music" folder inside.
Afterwards you should adapt your load statement and include the "music" folder in your path:

```
void Start()
{
    AudioSource audio = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    audio.PlayOneShot ((AudioClip)Resources.Load ("music/music"));
}
```

Comment: Michael it doesn't work.. i created a new c# file, and insert your code, then add the c# file on the camera.. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `audio.PlayOneShot((AudioClip)Resources.Load("music/music", typeof(AudioClip)));`

Comment: @GiwrgoLiasko Did you add the resources folder like Michael suggested?

Comment: If anyone else ends up here, I also needed to omit the file extension... i.e. copy "example.ogg" in the resource folder as advised but then `Resources.Load("example")`

Answer (score 0):

Its working when you just add the `.mp3` ending,

```
audio.PlayOneShot ((AudioClip)Resources.Load ("music.mp3"));
```